# Как обнулять таймаут jQuery при каждом клике?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мне нужно чтобы при каждом клике на label рядом появлялась кнопка на 4 секунды, и при каждом клике нужно чтобы она появлялась заново на 4 сек. Сейчас же таймер общий для всех кликов. Как быть?

```css
.check {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
}

.box-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1">
                    <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-2">
                    <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-3">
                    <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<div class="check">
  <label for="check-4">
                    <input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-5">
                    <input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <label for="check-6">
                    <input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Motul</span>
                   </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(".check label").click(function() {
    $('.box-button').show();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.box-button').hide();
    }, 4000);

    $(this).parent('.check').find('.box-button').appendTo(this);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Честно говоря, я не понял вашего вопроса, пожалуйста, напишите более подробно.

Comment: Кликая на label у меня появляется кнопка и исчезает через 4 секунды. Если кликнуть на label и подождать 2-3 сек, а потом кликнуть на другой label, то она пропадет через 1 секунду. То есть таймер при следующем клике не обнуляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кнопка нужна одна на все блоки, то `timeout` нужно вынести с более общую область видимости (хоть в window)

Например так:

```
$(function($) {
  var globalTimeout;
  $(".check label").click(function() {
    var $parentBox = $(this).closest('.check');
    $('.box-button').hide();
    $('.box-button', $parentBox).show();
    clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
    globalTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.box-button').hide();
    }, 4000);
    $('.box-button', $parentBox).appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

Вариант с независимыми кнопками в пределах блока:

```js
$(".check label").click(function() {
  var $parentBox = $(this).closest('.check');
  $('.box-button', $parentBox).show();
  clearTimeout($parentBox.data('timeout'));
  $parentBox.data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
    $('.box-button', $parentBox).hide();
  }, 4000));
  $('.box-button', $parentBox).appendTo(this);
});
```

```css
.check {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
}

.box-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1">
    <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span>
  </label>
  <label for="check-2">
    <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span>
  </label>
  <label for="check-3">
    <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span>
  </label>
    <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<div class="check">
  <label for="check-4">
    <input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span>
  </label>
  <label for="check-5">
    <input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span>
  </label>
  <label for="check-6">
    <input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span>
  </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так надо поправить.

```css
.check {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
}

.box-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1"><input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span></label>
  <label for="check-2"><input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span></label>
  <label for="check-3"><input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span></label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<div class="check">
  <label for="check-4"><input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span></label>
  <label for="check-5"><input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span></label>
  <label for="check-6"><input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox"><span>Motul</span></label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(".check label").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).parent('.check').find('.box-button');
    $(btn).appendTo(this);
    $(btn).show();

    clearTimeout($(btn).data('timer'));
    $(btn).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
      $(btn).hide();
    }, 4000));

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но даже на Вашем примере не работает. Нажмите, подождите 2-3 сек и кликните в другое место и заметите, что таймер не обнулился

Comment: да, я не совсем понял вопрос вначале. Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Поправил. Сейчас timeout записывается в данные кнопки. Поскольку кнопки две, то и таймаутов два. Если надо свой таймаут на каждый label - то у каждого должна быть своя кнопка.